# Algorithm: minimize the costs of rearranging piles

Tags: algorithm

I have come across this algorithmic problem that I was not able to solve: https://prologin.org/train/2017/semifinal/collection_de_feuilles (in French).

`N`, `K`, and `M[]` will be given as the input. `N` refers to the number of piles of items, and in `M[i]` is the number of items in the i-th pile. You can only merge the i-th pile of `M[i]` items into the j-th pile of `M[j]` items if j > i, and the cost of this merge is defined to be `M[i] * (j - i)`. The output is the minimum cost of merging the initial `N` piles into `K` piles.

My idea was to use a function `min_rearrange(x, num_piles)` which calculates the minimum cost to rearrange piles from `M[x]` to `M[N - 1]` into the specified number of piles. When `num_piles` is equal to 1, this function returns the sum of the the costs to move `M[j]` into `M[N -
 1]`, x ≤ j < N. Otherwise, since there must exist an `i` with x ≤ i ≤ N - num_piles that we move all the piles from `M[x]` to `M[i - 1]` into `M[i]`, we calculate that sum and then recursively call `min_rearrange(i + 1, num_piles - 1)` to find the minimum cost.

I have also tried to memoize the solutions:

```
# https://prologin.org/train/2017/semifinal/collection_de_feuilles
n, k = map(int, input().split())
piles = list(map(int, input().split()))
memory = {}


def min_rearrange(x, num_piles):
    """Min cost to rearrange piles[x:] into num_piles"""
    if (x, num_piles) in memory:
        return memory[x, num_piles]
    if num_piles == 1:
        memory[x, num_piles] = sum([(n - 1 - i) * piles[i] for i in range(x, n)])
        return memory[x, num_piles]
    min_cost = float('inf')
    for i in range(x, n - num_piles + 1):
        cost = sum([(i - j) * piles[j] for j in range(x, i)])
        min_cost = min(min_cost, cost + min_rearrange(i + 1, num_piles - 1))
    memory[x, num_piles] = min_cost
    return min_cost


print(min_rearrange(0, k))
```

But it takes too much time for large input sizes. I'd like to know how the problem can be solved more efficiently.